# Alternative Sorting Method for Citations

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I am currently working on a document (a thesis), and on one line I am required to make more than 100 citations in a single `\cite{}` command, and there is no way around this particular piece of phrasing.

Currently, my references are listed in citation order. However, many of the references in the `\cite{}` command are called before the 50-long citation note. The net result of this is that rather than grouping the citation in the text(e.g. 111-161), I am left with a string of numbers which shoots off the right hand side of the page.

There are a few of these cite commands in the paper, and there is overlap between the references. Citations cannot appear twice, so grouped citations do not help.

The solution which would suit me best is if there was a way to sort citations such that they 'clump' in an idealised fashion based on which groups they appear in the latex document. Does anyone know of such method, and how to implement it?

I currently use Bibtex, But am more than happy to transfer to Biblatex or similar.

Comment: I can imagine that if you are using **biblatex**, "transferring" to **biblatex** would not be a problem:-)

Comment: Can't you use some `\nocite` early in the document to force an effective order without the citations actually appearing in that position?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can do that, but it's not the optimal solution in terms of the fact that the rules re. my thesis state something to the effect that insofar as is practicable, citations should be in appearance order.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a compound citation (_i.e._ one number pointing to several papers)?

Comment: Ah, that is a caveat that I shall now add into the question- I have to cite several of these groups, which have significant overlap with each other, and my citations cannot appear twice.

Comment: I like Joseph's idea of the "supercite", but if that is not allowed, is it possible to point to a footnote, where then you can in a more deliberate fashion lay out the 100 cites in an orderly way?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - that is an option on the table, but from how it looks on paper it's a less than optimal workaround.

Comment: @PhilipAdler I don't see why `\nocite` doesn't address the concern, other than the fact that you have to do the grouping manually. the first time that you \cite a reference that later you want to be part of a group, add \nocite at that point for the rest of that group. Do this separately for each group.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle doing the grouping manually when I have >400 references, some 200ish would need manual sorting is exactly the reason why such a solution is not practicable at this stage.

Comment: @PhilipAdler not ideal but I doubt bibtex could do the analysis required to group automatically, perhaps biblatex, as that has some more information available, but I don't know that so well, but others may answer for that. But really If you have a list of 200 \nocite at the beginning of the document  you have full control over the order. So probably I'd do that and if its big enough to be managed separate;y generate that list from perl or any programming language of choice that can do the analysis of the adjacent citations to derive the groups. Sorry best I can offer:-)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the package cite (by Donald Arseneau)

```
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite
```

The effect of this package is to make the citations breakable (the LaTeX default is unfortunately that the citations are unbreakable).

Comment: I currently use said package- the aim is to eliminate the long string, not only to make it wrap over the lines.

Comment: \bibliographystyle{unsrt} is probably what you also want: It numbers the the citations by their occurence in the text and sorts them accordingly in the bibliography.

Comment: Already using that too, I am afraid.